# signal and slot in QT

Tags: c++, wpf, qt

i have a problem in working signal and slot in QT framework .
my slot is not working .
here is the code .

```
       connect(&th,SIGNAL(change()),this,SLOT(closeWindow()));
       this->moveToThread(th);
       closeWindow();
       th.start();
```

"th" is a var from a class like this :

```
    class Thread : public QThread
    {
    public :
        Thread();
        bool pause,flag;
        QString URL;
        QFile *mFile;
        void run();
        void RESUME();
        void PAUSE();
        bool Check();
        bool Check2();
    signals:
        void change();
        QString myTxt;
    };
```

"change" is the signal

and here is the code of my MainWindow :

```
     namespace Ui {
     class MainWindow;
     }
     class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
     {
Q_OBJECT
     public:
         explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
         ~MainWindow();
        Thread th;
     private slots:
         void on_pushButton_clicked();
     private:
         Ui::MainWindow *ui;
     public slots:
         void closeWindow();
     };
```

and here is the constructor for MainWindow

```
     MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
         QMainWindow(parent),
         ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
     {
         ui->setupUi(this);
         connect(&th,SIGNAL(change()),this,SLOT(closeWindow()));
         th.start();
     }
```

the signal is Ok . but the Slot is not Working .
can You guide me ?

Comment: We can't see in your code where the signal is emitted (we can't even see *if* it's emitted). Your first snippet can't work: the variable th is an object and moveToThread takes a pointer as argument. Please provide an [MCVE](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjt8d_-vJPOAhVPahoKHdeFBPUQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fmcve&usg=AFQjCNEkKReghNZHBJSaky_hwPskMmG0ww&sig2=qJFt1v76F13Ikk_8pOIvMQ)

Comment: i sent the signal right now for you @wasthishelpful

Comment: when is emit it the signal work (i test and write some code into it and they run cool ) @wasthishelpful

Comment: can you explain more about "moveToThread" ? @wasthishelpful

Comment: Mistake 1: [do not subclass QThread](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/). Mistake 2: Missing `Q_OBJECT` macro. Mistake 3. Multi threading is to hard for you, you are a newbie so master basics first.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is that the receiving object lives in a dead thread.

Your `Thread` instance lives on the application thread, while your `MainWindow` lives on the thread created by your `Thread` instance. However as you have reimplemented `QThread::run()`, you do not have an event loop on this thread and the slot can never be invoked.

Check Qt documentation for details:

- [Threading Basics](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html)
- [Threads and QObjects](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html)

---

Also you have some big issues in your code:

- Missing Q_OBJECT macro in `Thread` definition (but you might have removed it while copy/pasting otherwise you wouldn't be able to emit the signal).
- You must not call `moveToThread()` on object derived from `QWidget` (e.g `QMainWindow`). QWidgets must live on the application thread.
- You generally cannot mix using `moveToThread()` and reimplementing `run()`.

  - When using `moveToThread()` you are using the thread event loop to make QObjects living on this thread (i.e moved to this thread) live.
  - When reimplementing `QThread::run()`, people generally want to execute a single function on a thread. This will lead to a thread being created, the function executed and the thread destroyed without running an event loop. And no event loop mean that if a QObject lives on this thread, it will not received inter-thread slot invokations.

*NB: Using `moveToThread()` is the correct/intended way to use `QThread`. Reimplementing `QThread::run()` will work and can be found in Qt documentation but isn't generally recommended and you might be better of using `QThreadPool`.*

More readings: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/